# Building double one-to-many relation in Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ado.net

Scenario details:

- Two Entities (Team, Match)
- Two relations 'one-to-many' between them (for host and guest team)

Problem:

```
+========+      +========+
|Club    |------|Match   |
+--------|1    *+--------|
|Id      |      |Id      |
|Name    |------|Date    |
+--------|1    *+--------|
|Matches1|      |ClubHome|
|Matches2|      |ClubAway|
+========+      +========+
```

Two FK for Match entity appears under Team entity after creating two 'one-to-many' relations. How can I get rid of second one to have only one FK under Team (for Matches)?

Or maybe there is a better way to solve this problem? Thanks and best regards. (I'm creating 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' using 'Visual Studio 2013').